# Compute mean value over a sliding window in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, mean, reshape, moving-average

I have a time series data or considering a real valued data of length `N`. I want to create sub-blocks of length `k`, which is the window length. The value of `k` can be arbitrarily chosen. This creates problem since the window size is the same across the data. I want to store each subblock in an array. But I am stuck in creating sub-blocks of the data and to include a check so that the `(mod(N, nseg))` `nseg` must be divisible by the data length.

```
N = 512; %length of the time series
data = rand(N,1);
window_length = 30;  %k
Nseg = floor(N/window_length) %Number of segments or blocks

Modified_Data = [mean(reshape(data,window_length,Nseg))]; %Throws error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Image Processing toolbox you could use `im2col` to slide a specific block size over the entire time series. Each column of the output represents the data from one of those blocks.

```
values = im2col(data, [window_length 1], 'distinct');
```

Since it looks like you just want the mean over each block, you could also use `blockproc` to do this.

```
means = blockproc(data, [window_length, 1], @(x)mean(x.data));
```

If you do not have the Image Processing Toolbox, you can instead use `accumarray` to perform this task.

```
means = accumarray(floor((0:(N-1)).'/window_length) + 1, data, [], @mean);
```

If you want to discard any data that extends beyond a number which is divisible by `window_length`, you can do this with something like the following:

```
data = data(1:(numel(data) - mod(numel(data), window_length)));
```

If you want overlapping data, you'll either want to use straight-up convolution (the preferred method)

```
means = conv(data(:), ones(5, 1)/5, 'same');
```

Or you can create overlapping blocks with `im2col` by omitting the last input.

```
values = im2col(data, [window_length 1]);
means = mean(values 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do have the im2col() function. I would like to know that apart from creating non-overlapping blocksizes, how can I apply the method to create overlapping blocks? I do not want the mean value over sliding window for overalpping. Let the data contain 5 elements say data = [1,2,3,4,5]. Then the blocks would be blck1 =  (0,1); blk2 = (1,2); blk3 = (2,3); blk4 = (3,4); blk5 = (4,5)? So, could you please put up an answer for non-overlapping (the one that you already have) and for the overlapping case that I have mentioned in this comment? Thank you very much!

Comment: You would just want to omit the 3rd input to `im2col`: `im2col([1 2 3 4 5], [1 2])`

Comment: @SrishtiM Updated.

Answer (score 2):

If you have R2016a+, consider using the built-in [`movmean`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmean.html) function:

```
N = 512; %length of the time series
data = rand(N,1);
window_length = 30;  %k
Modified_Data = movmean(data, window_length);
```

See the documentation for further details and other options.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it's pretty straightforward:

```
filter(ones(N,1)/N,1,signal)
```

If you think about it filtering with [1/N 1/N 1/N...1/N] is exactly calculating the localized mean...

Comment: @Suever you can just choose every `N` elements of the result. Otherwise, `conv` might be more straightforward here than `filter`, maybe they're the same for that kernel but `conv` definitely gives you the means